# NoMethodError in ChatRoomMessagesController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I am doing an AJAX call as the following and trying to parse the JSON recieved in Rails as bellow

**AJAX**

```
local_data = {chat:{room_name: chatRoomName ,message: message}}
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/chat_notify',
        dataType: 'json',
        async : false,
        data: local_data,
        success: function(data) {
            alert("working");
        }
      });
```

**Ruby**

```
def notify
    #data = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(params)

    #chat_room = ChatRoom.where(:slug =>  data.chat.name)
    #puts @chat_room

    puts params.chat
    RestClient.post 'https://api.pushbots.com/push/all',
    { "platform" => [0,1] ,
      "msg" => "Harsha sent a message." ,
      "sound" => "pulse",
      "alias" => "harsha@mink7.com",
      "badge" => "1",
      "payload" => { "type" => "Chat", "chat_id" => 1 } }.to_json,
      headers = { "x-pushbots-appid" => APP_CONFIG['PUSHBOTS_APPID'],
                  "x-pushbots-secret" => APP_CONFIG['PUSHBOTS_SECRET'],
                  :content_type => :json }

    render json: true
  end
```

**Error**

Comment: FYI Error is missing

Comment: Please show the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to paste your error trace

But I think the problem might in below

`puts params.chat`

there is no chat method for `params` , just remove it

or

`…………"payload" => { "type" => "Chat", "chat_id" => 1 } }.to_json`

you need `require 'json'` to make `.to_json` available